# Not able to erase vector element using iterator, vector element implements the move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector of struct Cache. Cache which implements Move constructor. Whenever I try to iterate over this vector and try to erase an element on specific condition it fails to compile.

```
struct Cache {
    Cache() {}

    Cache(Cache&& other)
        : serviceName(std::move(other.serviceName))
    {}

    ~Cache() {}

    size_t referenceCount;
    std::string serviceName;
};

std::vector<Cache> vectorCaches;
auto iter = vectorCaches.begin();
while(iter != vectorCaches.end()) {
     if(iter->serviceName == "Sample") {
         iter = vectorCaches.erase(iter); //compiler error here
     } else {
         iter++;
     }
}
```

Compiler error:

> error: use of deleted function 'Cache& Cache::operator=(const Cache&)'
>           *__result = std::move(*__first);
>                     ^ note: 'Cache& Cache::operator=(const Cache&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'Cache' declares a move
>   constructor or move assignment operator
>        struct Cache {

Is there any workaround to achieve erase when vector element implements move constructor? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try making your move constructor  `noexcept`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Doesn't the OP need to define a move assignment operator?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, indeed.

Comment: Is this the entire code? Your `while` loop looks incomplete (no increment of the iterator, no `break` when the condition is matched).

Comment: @FelixLauer: The `break` is probably not appropriate. Clue: the OP has gone out of their way to leave `iter` valid for the next iteration, and the container is a vector, which may contain duplicates.

Comment: Also note in this case you do not need to define any constructors except one to populate the cache members if you want.  All the other special member functions will be generated by the compiler.

Comment: @FelixLauer: Updated the sample code so that there won't be infinite loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By creating a move constructor and not a copy constructor, you have made your type non-copyable.

That's fine, but a vector requires that your elements can be copied or moved around in its storage space, particularly when you remove from the container and all the following elements have to be shuffled down. It does this by assignment.

So, you can keep your class moveable and uncopyable, but you do need to write a **move assignment operator**.

Generally: if you write a copy constructor, write a copy assignment operator; and, if you write a move constructor, write a move assignment operator.

By the way, your loop is broken; it does not progress through the container if the service name *doesn't* match.

Comment: Generally, sticking to basic design rules (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) may help circumvent these kinds of issues.

Comment: @FelixLauer: The rule of zero is better.

Comment: Ah, I see the page has a misleading URI :)

Comment: one? never heard that one

Comment: @GillBates: The rule of one is "always use the rule of zero"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It was the first match on Google :D But yeah, the rule of zero is appropriate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'd love to see that published in a book.

Comment: @GillBates: Does the periodic Stack Exchange DB data dump count? :D

Comment: I have added the move assignment operator, now it compiles fine without any issues. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code:

```
Cache(Cache&& other)
    : serviceName(std::move(other.serviceName))
{}
```

It serves no good purpose.  It even looks buggy, and if not buggy extremely surprising.

Replace with:

```
Cache(Cache&& other)=default;
Cache(Cache const& other)=default;
Cache& operator=(Cache&& other)=default;
Cache& operator=(Cache const& other)=default;
```

Or, in some cases, omit all 4.  I like making them explicitly defaulted.

The compiler error is because creating `Cache(Cache&&)` implicitly gets rid of the other member functions above, in particular `operator=(Cache&&)` which `vector.erase` uses.

Comment: I have made these changes and tried. Its resolves the issue. The struct provided here is a miniaturized one, the actual struct is quite bigger than this and its better for me to keep the move constructor. Anyway thanks for the insight:)